# Use Prolog to get data model paths from language rules?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, dcg

I want to build a semi-natural language interface for a data warehouse. A simple data model looks for example like this:

```
Company
- attribute 'name'
- reference to 'Departments'

Department
- attribute 'type'
- reference to 'Employees'

Employee
- attribute 'age'
- attribute 'salary'
```

And I would like to make queries like so:

`ACME employees`, `Bugs Bunny salary`, `ACME department types` etc.

For input that is not in the grammar, I would call the database and resolve say `ACME` into `Company`.

... and turn the queries into paths that my database language will understand:

`[Company].departments.employees`, `[Employee].salary`, `[Company].departments.type`.

I remember using SWI-Prolog way back when to parse English sentences and say if they are correct. Is Prolog still the way to go in this case?

Thanks

Comment: search for dcg in prolog

Comment: @whd thanks! Have gone through a few DCG and 'Prolog as a Database Query Language' tutorials and got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even, better, I now use DCG with embedded Prolog rules.

So, for a model that has classes and attributes like this:

```
c(company, class(company)) --> [company].
a(company, attribute(name)) --> [name].
```

I can ask for attributes of a class of a class:

```
q(q(A,C1,C2)) --> a(T1,A), [of], c(T1,C1)
    ,[of], c(T2,C2), {is_child(T1, T2)}.
```

And get a tree back as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog, there is [Chat80](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=chat80) ready to install. I think could be very similar to what you are after, mutatis mutandis.

Just a sample query from the session log (note: was my own old port of chat80 to SWI-Prolog, the pack is presumably more functional, but I haven't tried to run):

```
what rivers are there ? 

Parse: 0.0168457sec.
whq
   $VAR
      1
   s
      np
         3+plu
         np_head
            int_det(B)
            []
            river
         []
      verb(be,active,pres+fin,[],pos)
      void
      []



Semantics: 0.0170898sec.
answer([B]) :-
   river(B)
 & exists B 
     true

Planning: 0.0sec.
answer([B]) :-
   river(B)
 & exists B 
     true
amazon, amu_darya, amur, brahmaputra, colorado, congo_river, cubango, danube, don, elbe, euphrates, ganges, hwang_ho, indus, irrawaddy, lena, limpopo, mackenzie, mekong, mississippi, murray, niger_river, nile, ob, oder, orange, orinoco, parana, rhine, rhone, rio_grande, salween, senegal_river, tagus, vistula, volga, volta, yangtze, yenisei, yukon and zambesi.

Reply: 0.166992sec.
```

The logical form required by discourse to answer a query it's the central point of the system. Not really easy to craft from ground!

I read the book `Prolog and Natural Language Analysis`, F.Pereira, S.Shieber, 1987
 (translated in Italian), still my preferred! The english original it's freely available [here](http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/pnla.html).

Comment: Thanks for the Chat80 reference. Luckily, the scope of the queries I am making is smaller and the language is way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Have ended up with this example that translates a 'sentence' into a path in the model:

```
% root classes
class(ceo).

% model relations
attribute_of(age, ceo).
attribute_of(salary, ceo).

% grammar of relations
attribute('age', age).
attribute('salary', salary).
attribute('money', salary).

% answer format
answer([Class, Attribute], Class, Attribute).

% language rules
% query(Attribute,'of',Object, Answer).
query(AttributeQ, 'of', ClassQ, Answer) :-
    db(ClassQ, Class), attribute(AttributeQ, Attribute), attribute_of(Attribute, Class), answer(Answer, Class, Attribute).

% database
db('Bugs Bunny', ceo).
```

As an example, the following query:

`?- query('age','of','Bugs Bunny', Answer).`

...gives me:

`Answer = [ceo, age].`